# WinSCP for Linux

Tags: windows, 20.04, sync, ftp, alternative

I've always used WinSCP for Windows to keep my directories up to date with the sync option. This is a really useful feature that most FTP clients lack.

Now I started programming on Ubuntu and, since there's no WinSCP versione for this OS and searching for an alternative.

Is there any other FTP software with this `/keepuptodate` option which works for Linux?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you mean `rsync` and similar tools, perhaps? You seem to be asking more for a software recommendation than for a clean cut answer to a specific problem. [This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna ask the question there

Comment: You can install WinSCP using wine.

Comment: @Pilot6 is it a sort of Windows virtual Box? I already have Windows, so I don't need an operating system emulator but I would like to use Windows apps on Linux

Comment: we use the file manager for things like this. sftp://root@servername/directory in Nautilus or fish://servername. in Konqueror. Filezilla is probably the go-to option if you want a piece of software but there is no scripting or scheduler available :(

Comment: @Rinzwind is there a `keepuptodate` option for Nautilus?

Comment: It is not a virtual windows. It is a way of running Windows programs on Linux.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you, I will try it

Comment: I am using WinSCP this way. Because there is no perfect replacement by native Linux apps.

Comment: @Pilot6 Rinzwind talked about Nautilus... Do you know whether there's a `keepuptodate` option using that and if it could be somehow better that WinSCP?

Comment: No there will not be one. I would use a directorywatcher for something like that.